# Adobe Granite HTML Library Manager

Tags: aem

In Adobe Granite HTML library Manager, How "**max data uri size**" works?
I tried an image with a lot of data size in the configuration.But there is no
change.
Can someone tell me how this configuration works in AEM?

Comment: What are you expecting or are you just looking for a change in output? The documentation on this property is pretty clear as to what it does so are you saying that it is not functioning as expected? Can you tell us more about your CSS and referenced asset setup along with config and sizes to see if there is any issue.

Comment: My expectations are if i set an image using data URI,It has a max data size defined in this configuration and if my image data size go beyond that, Then the image should not get loaded.

Comment: Nope, that's not what this setting is for. The image will be inlined into the CSS as Base64 image data based on this limit. Not sure whether it's the limit of the Base64 encoded data or the image itself. Best to test along these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minification of css-files can auto-inline small resources (e.g. icons). The config-parameter **htmllibmanager.maxDataUriSize** steers maximum size for resources to be auto-inlined.

Here is an example css:

```
#tiny-icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-image: url("tiny-icon.gif");
}
```

My sample-icon has a size of 360 bytes. With maxDataUriSize <= 360, the minified css file will look:

```
#tiny-icon{height:32px;width:32px;background-image:url("test-alex/tiny-icon.gif")}
```

With maxDataUriSize > 360, the icon will be auto-inlined as data-url:

```
#tiny-icon{height:32px;width:32px;background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAIQQAEeczSqmzligoGmarl6khnCdy3CpaBjo9Gbuk4HxcbLf1Gb35tnhhtna19T2NO/w7////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEKABAALAAAAAAgACAAAAXlYCGOZCkOhBGsgOm+I6qycF3Ka9DaPErkO17NBxSSHshHY8lwOA6LhWJJpdaS1OYzOq1Wr0qmEyr1Vh/XrCNB7pobyJqazX0vk/JGk162J9EwemttdnB/NXuEfn+ALgKDdYuMLwIGfG5mjHgjAiKVBIpvmpsFlaUGBACRoqNKnqifAAF9rJpWsaiyAZherVWxAQK6BYW+WbksKyKSjFVNqcrKy5mjzmvDBTojvcZibNIm3LZzUAGBd92CCGR5rWFi61xy7tbxC0tGLwOVwuD5JvsM9DP3z0XAgQUN8sOWkMRBhjBCAAA7")}
```

*If you want to test it by yourself, please be aware that client-libs are cached. Either delete the cache in /var/clientlibs, or update the css file. Otherwise the configuration changes will have no effect, as you will still see the cached version of the clientlib.*

Comment: @Alexender I tried it as usual you explained.But it is not working as it is always coming as simple path not in the encoded manner. Have u tried it by yourself?

Comment: @shivani-garg I tried it with a pretty fresh AEM 6.2 quickstart. I exported it as a package http://www.alexanderberndt.com/tmp/test-alex-clientlib.zip.

Comment: @shivani-garg The sample client-lib is then available at http://localhost:4502/etc/clientlibs/test-alex.min.css . And please dont forget to clean the cache in /var/clientlibs. In your web-page you get the minified version only, if you enabled minification - and really used the client-lib-manager.

Comment: Fabulous explanation.Really appreciating.But still it's a question for me that why it was not working on my part. Your package is working btw.Thanks.

Comment: Does it not work in your AEM installation? (then maybe your project replaced the minifier). Or just your resource. Then maybe you can send me an package via e-mail (see my website)